# How do I clean everything of God Eater resurrection in my PC+?

Tags: god-eater-resurrection

Like in the title said how should I clean everything of God Eater Resurrection in my PC? After over using cheat trainer I bugged my game, I can't acquire any materials after completing mission and can't advance to mission 73 I'm stuck in mission 72.

Answer (score 1):

There are special uninstallation tools that can do a thorough file and registry search for everything related to a specific program. I use Revo Uninstaller when I need such a tool, but others are available. Be careful though, these tools have a tendency of removing digital distribution platforms like Steam, uPlay and Origin (along with every game installed) if not used right.

Note that it's possible that your saved game is corrupted because you cheated, so first try to start a new game and see if the problem exists in fresh games. You may have to return to mission 73.

Comment: i tried new game but it  same.

Comment: then try using Revo Uninstaller. +1 for that software, it's very powerful

Comment: @V4karian I did Revo Uninstaller but it didn't work.